# What is "result" when using the Fetch API?

Tags: javascript

I have seen a few examples online that use `result` within a `then` method chained onto the fetch method. In an effort to try to understand `result` in the Fetch API, the following code was created. The JSON returns fine and is logged to the console. `result` is undefined. What exactly is `result`, and why is it undefined?

```
fetch('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts', {
  method: 'get'
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return response from first `then` & extract JSON payload from that response once the request completes. Similarly if you wish to use the result of this fetch call you have to return the response from the second `then` or add code for consuming the response

```js
fetch('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! So what is the formal definition of `result`? Cannot seem to find it anywhere online.

Comment: `result` is a programmer-named parameter of an anonymous function.  `elephant` or `banana` will work just as well if you are consistent.

Comment: So I see you can name this variable anything. Is it just representing what is returned from the then statement preceding it?

Comment: Yes that is true.  But don't get too creative.  You might confuse others, or your future self.

Answer (score 1):

When in a `.then` chain, the argument of a `.then` will be the resolve value of the value returned from the previous `.then` in the chain. Here, since you aren't returning anything from the first `.then`, the second `.then`'s argument is `undefined`.

You probably meant to do something like

```
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
  return response.json();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest use of `fetch()` takes one argument — the path to the resource you want to fetch — and returns a promise containing the response (a `Response` object).

You can checkout `Response` object interface https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

`Response` object has a method `json()` which is used to parsing the `body` text as `JSON`.

```js
fetch('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts', {
  method: 'get'
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response) // Response object
  return response.json() // Return a promise
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result) // We get out body text as JSON
});
```

You can use `async/await`

```js
async function fetchCats() {
      let response = await fetch("https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts");
      let result = await response.json();
      console.log(result);
}

fetchCats();
```